# Getting titles from playlist in the youtube api(python)

Tags: python, youtube-api

Problem is to get titles of each item in video list and print it, but print function doesn't work in function and doesn't see variable out of function.

A little more edited text

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.youtube.com/chanel/UC1ctnuRGUUXe04EgbsYXwPQ"
PLAYLIST_ID = 'PLg5SS_4L6LYueOJFm-IdWSuLiYwcASkH-'
APIKEY = '***********'


def get_items():

        YOUTUBE_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems'
        FORMAT = {'key': APIKEY, 'part': 'snippet', 'playlistId': PLAYLIST_ID, 'maxResults': 50}
        FORMAT_YOUTUBE_URI = (YOUTUBE_URI, FORMAT)
        content = requests.get(FORMAT_YOUTUBE_URI).json()

        video_list = []
        keys = 'id', 'title', 'description'

        for item in content('items'):
            id = item.get('id').get('videoId')
            title = item.get('snippet').get('title')
            description = item.get('snippet').get('description')
            values = id, title, description

            if id:
                video_item = dict(zip(keys, values))
                video_list.append(video_item)
                print('\n'.join(video_list))
                return video_list
```

Comment: You should not publish your API key. I have proposed an edit where the key is censored. If you want to be on the safe side, re-create your API key in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Thank you)))) But it is open api key, and project is just for training))) anyway, I will pay attention for that in the next project

Answer (score 1):

`content` variable is never used and from what I can see is where the data is. Besides `vide_list` is used but never filled with useful data, just initialized with an empty list `[]`

I highly recommend you use some sort of editor to help you to easily spot such things.

After your EDIT:

```
content = requests.get(FORMAT_YOUTUBE_URI).json()
```

is the problematic thing, not the logic that come, so you should concentrate in be able to make a Youtube API request right and then see how to process the result.